# how can we do popup background disable when we click on anywhere in the relevent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a button when i click on it i show a popup with disable background but if  i click on anywhere in the page except popup it is not enabling

```
<a href="#" onClick="pop('popDiv')">Click here to open a popup div</a>

<a href="#" onClick="hide('popDiv')">Close</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pop(div) {
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
}
function hide(div) {
    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
}
//To detect escape button
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        hide('popDiv');
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: add your code fiddle, so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: do you want the background to be disabled when popup is open?

Comment: when i open popup, background is disabled but if i click on anywhere in the page popup has to hide and page should be enable

Comment: hi @Rameshvemula .. I think you have to add "window.onclick"  to hide modal , while click  anywhere in page.

Answer (score 0):

simple just set the pointer-event property in css so it will not dismiss

pointer-event:none
see this :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides the easy implementation of popups.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Modal Popup Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Modal Popup Example</h2>
      <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If you want only javascript,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```